# Can't override a method in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I don't usually post something this simple, but this issue kept me scratching my head for while.

I'm trying to override a method in a subclass, but I get the following error message:

[image]

My `BitCompressor.java` iextends `Compressor.java` and attempts to override its `encodeInput(...)` method, but when I compile, I get the following error: `error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

The screenshot above shows the original method (middle), the subclass trying to override that method (top) and the error (bottom).

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: remove the `static`  keyword. You cant override a `static` method

Comment: @flakes thanks! can you post your answer as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Also please don't add images of code. [There are many reasons why you shouldn't.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479156)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the static keyword. You cant override a static method

To override a method it needs to be a normal instance method with visibility by the super class (ie public, protected or possibly package private) and not be marked final.

Every non-static method in Java is by default a virtual method except for final and private methods. These virtual methods are polymorphic and allow overriding.